# Decompose some algebraic sets into irreducibles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Find the irreducible components of $$V(Y^2-XY-X^2Y+X^3),\ V(Y^2-X(X^2-1)),\ V(X^3+X-X^2Y-Y)$$ in $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb R)$ and also in $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb C)$.

1. Now for $V(Y^2-XY-X^2Y+X^3)$,

$Y^2-XY-X^2Y+X^3=(Y-X^2)(Y-X)$

and both $Y-X^2$ and $Y-X$ are irreducible in $\Bbb R[X,Y],\ \Bbb C[X,Y]$.

So, $$V(Y^2-XY-X^2Y+X^3)=\{(a,a) : a \in \Bbb R\} \cup \{(a,a^2) : a \in \Bbb R\},$$ $$V(Y^2-XY-X^2Y+X^3)=\{(a,a) : a \in \Bbb C\} \cup \{(a,a^2) : a \in \Bbb C\}=V(Y-X) \cup V(Y-X^2).$$ Now can I write $$V(Y-X^2)=V(Y-X^2| X\geq 0) \cup V(Y-X^2| X< 0)$$ in $\Bbb R$? Again in is $Y-X^2=I(X)$ for some $X \subseteq \Bbb A^2(\Bbb C)$. I think these are irreducible component in $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb R)$ and $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb C)$ resp.

2. For $V(Y^2-X(X^2-1))$

$Y^2-X(X^2-1)=0 \Rightarrow Y^2=X(X^2-1)$. So $$V(Y^2-X(X^2-1))=\{(a,\pm\sqrt{a^3-a}): a^3-a \geq 0\}=V(Y^2-X(X^2-1 ): Y >0) \cup V(Y^2-X(X^2-1 ): Y\leq0)$$ and same question in $\Bbb C$.

3. For $V(X^3+X-X^2Y-Y)$

I can't separate it into two polynomials so I don't know how to do this?

Please help in clearing my doubts... Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second polynomial is irreducible over any field, while the third equals $(X-Y)(X^2+1)$.

Comment: How to prove that about the second one? And what about the first one?

Comment: The second one is irreducible by the Eisenstein criterion.

Comment: Okay and the first one in $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb R)$ and in $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb C)$??

Comment: Means $$V(Y-X^2)=V(Y-X^2| X\geq 0) \cup V(Y-X^2| X< 0)$$ in $\Bbb R$ or $V(Y-X^2)$ is itself irreducible component?

Comment: $V(Y-X^2| X\geq 0)$ and $V(Y-X^2| X< 0)$ are not algebraic sets, as far as I can tell.  How could you write either of them as the vanishing locus of a set of polynomials?

Comment: Actually I am little bit confused in making a comment in these things. Can you please tell me what is $V(XY-1)$ in $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb R)$? I think we have two irreducible components in $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb R)$, so how to express it?

Comment: @user152715 As my answer shows, $V(XY-1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb A^2(\mathbb R)$ since $XY-1\in\mathbb R[X,Y]$ is irreducible, and  $V(XY-1)$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all three cases you have found some irreducible polynomials $f$ such that $V(f)$ is infinite. In this case, as you can see in Corollary 3.7 from [these notes](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Bloom.pdf), $V(f)$ is irreducible.

Only the third case doesn't fit completely into the frame described above: $V(X^2+1)=\emptyset$ over $\mathbb R$, and $V(X^2+1)=\{-i,i\}$ over $\mathbb C$.